# PHP: Get HTTP Protocol Version (HTTP/1.1 vs HTTP/2)

Tags: php, http, http2, http-1.1

Until now my php application assumed HTTP 1.1 everywhere. So I defined all headers like so:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
```

But now my server also supports HTTP 2 and I want to update all header responses with the right HTTP status code.

How to I get the HTTP Protocol version of the http request?

(My webserver is nginx, but I guess it is irrelevant if I am using nginx or apache.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The server protocol should be available through `SERVER_PROTOCOL` from the server environment, usually exposed through `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` inside your application.

From `phpinfo()` under Apache 2.4:

```
SERVER_PROTOCOL => HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

changing `/etc/nginx/factcgi_params:`

```
#fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    HTTP/2.0;
```

Header should be:-

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
```

Comment: FYI a space is missing before the '404'.