# Can I return "HTTP/1.1" protocol version when using HTTP/2?

Tags: http, http2

On my project, I've some hardcoded HTTP status codes and descriptions, such as:

```
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable entity");
```

And I'm not clear about [Section 8.1.3 of HTTP/2 specs](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#rfc.section.8.1.3) because it looks like a HTTP/2 server doesn't return anymore the full header line (protocol, status code, and status description). For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 123
```

Would become:

```
HEADERS
  + END_STREAM
  + END_HEADERS
:status = 200
content-type = image/jpeg
content-length = 123
```

When using my [demo](https://demo.jorani.org/), browsers don't look to be bothered by responses starting by "HTTP/1.1".

So I am wondering if it is urgent to rely on the framework for returning a proper status code (the framework builds a string starting by $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']). See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718412/php-get-http-protocol-version-http-1-1-vs-http-2) for implementation. Or if it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said there is no textual status line in the HTTP/2 protocol, which could be used to transfer a string that includes "HTTP/1.1". HTTP/2 only transmits the status code in numerical form in the pseudoheader value `:status`, which would be picked up by the client.

So the main question is what the framework of your choice is doing when you call

```
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable entity");
```

If the framework would in the HTTP/2 case parse this line, extract only the `422` and put it in the `:status` pseudoheader then everything is fine. If it would not parse it, then I don't know how it would be able to set a status code. Your framework/webserver also can't use this string as a normal header - since what you set here is only a single string value. Setting a normal header would require the name and the value of the header. So I guess your framework just drops the irrelevant data and everything is fine.

What you could do if you are interested is using the `nghttp2` commandline tool `nghttp` to debug the connection. Make a call like `nghttp -v https://your-host` and it will debug-print you all received header values including the pseudo-headers.